# Unexpected element behavior with css image centering

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get this image centered in the page for a while, and for some reason `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` weren't doing anything. So in the spirit of wildly trying everything in sight, I stumbled on the following surprisingly correct result. My question is, why on earth does setting the width to 25% work? I would have expected 100%, or 50% at least.

This fiddle shows some other widths, which apparently behave in a nonlinear fashion: http://jsfiddle.net/mo85kkvv/

(Bonus question: is there a super-obvious way to use the margin-left/right properties instead that I'm missing?)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="bcontainer">
        <img src="banner.png" alt="banner" />
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#bcontainer {
    width: 25%; /* why 25%?? */
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Must it be in a `display: table-cell` element? This doesn't appear to be a table-based layout (in that it looks nothing like a table).

Comment: It looks to me as though `width:25%` isn't actually applied - http://jsfiddle.net/mo85kkvv/1/

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/mo85kkvv/3/

Comment: @BoltClock Nope, that was just a dumb thing that happened to work and I forgot to change it. This seems to suffice, from @Paulie_D's fiddle: `#bcontainer > img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

Is what your after ? http://jsfiddle.net/mo85kkvv/4/

---

HTML

---

```
    <body>
    <div class="container" id="one">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/J/D/n/z/V/gold-scroll-banner.svg" alt="banner" />
    </div><br>

    <div class="container" id="two">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/J/D/n/z/V/gold-scroll-banner.svg" alt="banner" />
    </div><br>

    <div class="container" id="three">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/J/D/n/z/V/gold-scroll-banner.svg" alt="banner" />
    </div><br>

    <div class="container" id="four">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/J/D/n/z/V/gold-scroll-banner.svg" alt="banner" />
    </div>
</body>
```

---

CSS

---

```
       body {

       }
        .container img{
            width:100%;
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #one {
            width: 25%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #two {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #three {
            width: 75%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #four {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about HTML but I think that the proper way to define the class container is:

```
.container {
    height: auto;
   display: block;
   margin:auto;
}
```

This is more generic. You can use the element inspector, and see how the layers change.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you want. Do you want the wrapper to be centered with the image floating in the center, or do you want the wrapper (in this case `.container`) to shrink around the image and be the one that floats in the center? I have updated your fiddle with simple examples of a few options.

http://jsfiddle.net/mo85kkvv/6/